Affine connection and covariant derivative
I'm approaching the study of Riemannian geometry for the first time.
I have some doubts about the notions of Affine Connection and Covariant derivative. In particular, I seem to have understood that, when we try to define the directional derivative of Vector field along a Vector field we encounter the problem that there is not a natural way to identify tangent spaces on different point of the manifold. The the naive attempt to extend the well know notion on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is doomed to fail. In this contex we introduce the notion of Affine connection, that seems a machinery to derive a Vector field along a Vector field. At this point we introduce the convariant derivative, i.e. the derivative of a Vector field along a curve.
I know that these two objects properly are distinct, but, at least in this context, they seems to me almost the same thing.
Unfortunately, currently my background in geometry is not very extensive. However, I seem to have understood that the notion of connection is a useful concept that is used as an operation between vector bundles, while in the context of Riemannian geometry it in some sense coincides with the notion of covariant derivative.
Can anyone give me an overview of these concepts?

What textbook are you reading?

The concept of an affine connection is the same as the concept of covariant differentiation. As for the directional derivative of a function, differentiation along a curve is the same thing as differentiation in the direction of a vector.

@MoisheKohan I'm studying from the notes taking in class. The textbook i am referring to is 'Do Carmo'.

@Deane Okay thanks. At my level, it seems strange to me that to do two such similar things two different objects are defined. Anyway thanks for the clarification
